# Is it safe to use base64_encode instead of mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been using `base64_encode` to preserve html from a `<textarea>` form and storing the data in the database.  Upon retrieval `base64_decode` is used and the data is put into the textarea. Is this safe to do without using `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

I do I use `mysql_real_escape_string` when retrieving the `$_GET` parameter of template `id`.

`templates.php?id=4`

However using base64 to preserve the html also preserves any malicious sql code one might add in the textarea. I have not had any problems, so far.

Is this bad practice to use base64 instead of `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

"Wrong tool for the job" ?

*Note: I use `htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);` for xss.*

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Do you really want to be storing base64 blobs in your database? It not only wastes space, it also prevents you from doing any operations on the data inside the database.

Comment: @deceze that is okay.  I do not run queries on the stored html, but the other parts that is mysql escaped I do.

Comment: @Truth sorry. I do plan to migrate to mysqli but for now this is just a small project.  I made a database class that is old mysql, but I can easily port it to mysqli. I just wasn't ready yet. Thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically `base64_encode` will never output anything that can be used for SQL injection. Insofar, it's safe.

However, I would make it a habit to *always* SQL escape *any* parameters used in *any* query or to always use parameterized queries to begin with (really, go with the times!). It's simpler, it's straight-forward, it won't open you to problems later when you change your code around.

Comment: Though, if you pass through text/html transparently like the OP, you have to look out for xss vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, base64 strings are safe to use in database. But it has some drawbacks.

- You'll need to encode and decode the string every time it enters/exists the database, whereas when you escape/prepare it, you only need to do it one.
- You're wasting space. base64 string is larger by about 33% than the original string.

Your best bet is to move to a more current MySQL driver (such as `mysqli` or `PDO`), and use prepared statements. When that's not possible for whatever reason, stick with `mysql_real_escape_string`.